# Flutter 3.7 + Firebase: Unable to establish connection on channel

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter and Firebase and try to get a connection from a plain "flutter create test" project. Read a lot of tutorials but all seem to use Flutter2 but my project is using 3.7.7 and it seems not to work in the old way.

I created a public Firestore and got a Flutter2 tutorial app connecting, reading and writing. So it seems that Firestore is configured correctly.

I got google-services.json and put it in android/app directory.

In my test project I added these dependencies in pubspec.yaml`

```
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  firebase_core:
```

In main.dart I added

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

When I try to run it I get this Exception:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

So any further configuration needed? Or do I miss something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all firebase dependencies to the latest version using `flutter pub outdated` and `flutter pub upgrade firebase_....`

Or try an older version of firebase.

Comment: Did a "flutter pub outdated" but all up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: it seems that for any reason it is not working as Windows app. Using my smartphone or an emulated Android device it works like expected.

Answer (score 0):

I did the silliest mistake possible - but documenting it here for others who might have made a similar mistake.

My READ and WRITE rules were disabled in Cloud Firestore Rules. The trick to fixing this was changing 'if false' to 'if true'.

[image]